# Make SOAP call with timeout - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, soap-client

I am trying to set up a timeout for this method. Actually, as you can see, I am doing a call to an external service and I need to set a timeout in case of failure. 
May you have any proposal? Is there any elegant way with Spring (annotation)?

```
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;


private SoapResponseWraper doCall(SOAPMessage request) throws SOAPException, IOException, TimeoutExceededException {
    log(Level.DEBUG, createMessage, request, REQUEST_HEADER);
    // Makes the call, get the response and prints it;
    SOAPMessage response = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection()
        .call(request, new URL(urlStr));
    SoapResponseWraper result = new SoapResponseWraper(response);
    log(Level.DEBUG, createMessage, response, RESPONSE_HEADER);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection` client you can use this:

```
private SoapResponseWraper doCall(SOAPMessage request) throws SOAPException, IOException, TimeoutExceededException {
    log(Level.DEBUG, createMessage, request, REQUEST_HEADER);
    // Makes the call, get the response and prints it;
    SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();

    URL endpoint = new URL(null,
                        urlStr,
                        new URLStreamHandler() { // Anonymous (inline) class
                        @Override
                        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                        URL clone_url = new URL(url.toString());
                        HttpURLConnection clone_urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) clone_url.openConnection();
                        // TimeOut settings
                        clone_urlconnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                        clone_urlconnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                        return(clone_urlconnection);
                        }
                    });
    SOAPMessage response = connection.call(request, endpoint);
    SoapResponseWraper result = new SoapResponseWraper(response);
    log(Level.DEBUG, createMessage, response, RESPONSE_HEADER);
    return result;
}
```

For Axis client you can use this:

```
private SoapResponseWraper doCall(SOAPMessage request) throws SOAPException, IOException, TimeoutExceededException {
    log(Level.DEBUG, createMessage, request, REQUEST_HEADER);
    // Makes the call, get the response and prints it;
    SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
    connection.setTimeout(10000);
    SOAPMessage response = connection.call(request, new URL(urlStr));
    SoapResponseWraper result = new SoapResponseWraper(response);
    log(Level.DEBUG, createMessage, response, RESPONSE_HEADER);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is for axis client. Can you tell me what specific libraries are you using?

Comment: Sure
`javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection`

Comment: I extended the answer for javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection

Comment: Thx! I 'll test it and I 'll post here as solved! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to use the [Circuit Breaker pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html)?
Spring Cloud Netflix provides [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) as implementation. Just annotate your Application class with `@EnableCircuitBreaker` or, more specific, `@EnableHystrix` and annotate your method `doCall(SOAPMessage request)` with `@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "10000")})`.

You can also add a `fallbackMethod` to your `@HystrixCommand` annotation to provide a method that will be invoked if something went wrong in the annotated method (including timeout).

This is the dependency you need to add in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

That's how Hystrix works: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works